Cannot install PWA on android?
I have a manifest.json correctly formatted, I can install the PWA from Chrome Desktop but not on Android.
But this is not only my app, I tried others and they all behave the same.
For example: https://mybio.social/
Even: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Guides/Making_PWAs_installable#how_do_you_make_an_app_a2hs-ready
Do I need a specific configuration on my device ?
Thank you in advance

What do you mean by "cannot install"? Do you see any error?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
